# Wrapping a set of stylesheets and javascript in a Ruby Gem with post build step to drop into right place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

We have a very complex library for styles and scripts that is maintained by a collaborative team.  This code is a large set of less, javascript, font and image files that is built using grunt and a number of modules installed with NPM.

What I want to do is have a post operation step in a gem that does this build and then copies the resulting files to the appropriate places.

Is there a way for this to happen in the Gem installation process itself so that I am not dependent on having to run a rake task or something.

I am trying to be as unobtrusive as possible on the existing project since it is part of a large enterprise wide initiative and is used by many other projects that are not rails etc.

File structure is rather cumbersome and I can't re-arrange, at least without running the npm install and grunt task.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to copy files at all.

Once such assets gem installed from Gemfile, it's assets path is available in app's assets lookup path. So you can use it directly in application.css and application.js, as well as image files.

Suppose your gem 'foo' structure is like this

```
foo
-lib
--foo
-vendor
--assets
---javascripts
----foobar.js
```

Then in your application.js you can do this

```
//= require foobar
```

Same is true for application.css.

You can keep the js build logic in gem, and only put the built `foobar.js` under vendor, so in Rails you only need to require one file.

Comment: The problem is I can't arrange the files this way.  The file structure is something like root/source/module/js/jsfile and root/source/module/less/lessfile with many modules.  I will have to list each js file separately as an asset config, which is one option.

What I want is for npm install to run, then grunt to run, compiling the assets into the above structure.  (I know, somewhat redundant, but there is a lot of code already in place for this that keeps us in sync with other projects)

There is some font compilation going on here too.

Comment: Bill, if you have difficulty on supplying assets directly from the lib, you can try this way: The Javascript project is dependent as it is. Then you build a gem doing nothing but copy the desired assets in correct folder and be responsible for Rails integration. Lots of assets gems do in this way.

Comment: I was going to do it this way, just copy the built output to the GEM, but one of my co-workers challenged me to integrate directly with the main project.  I feel this has diminishing returns, but I wanted to give it a try at least and see if it was possible.  I suspect it really isn't and we will continue to just drop the built output directly into our project rather than use a GEM.

Comment: Bill, that's viable as well and simpler. Just putting it in /vendor. It's a good choice if the lib is expected not to change often, and you don't want to opensource it.